# check if caps lock on iphone-sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uikeyboard

how i can check if caps on/off in the iphone-sdk?

maybe in the method `- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
}`?

(iOS 3.1.3+ , Xcode 4.4, Mac OS X Lion)

Comment: This seems like a strange thing you'd want to do. If you can give us what you're using it for, we might be able to help you better.

Comment: for password. image NO hidden when user clicked shift